# Apollo Query Components with react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

Following this blog, (https://dev-blog.apollodata.com/query-components-with-apollo-ec603188c157)

I can essentially pass a function to my parent, and the parent component will call the child with the appropriate parameters.

However I keep running into this error:

> Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you
>   return a Component instead of  from render. Or maybe you
>   meant to call this function rather than return it.

Is anyone else experiencing the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

I was using React Fragments in my query component. However, this does not work well with react-native. switching to use a view fixed my issue.